# Oracle Forms: Run form and run report from an pl/sql command

Tags: forms, oracle

I'm developing a program with Oracle Forms [32 Bit] Version 10.1.2.0.2 (Production) and Oracle Reports. I'm trying to create a program that would allow the end user to check and insert new data into the database. I have a main form, which has a main menu, which allows users to navigate to certain parts of the program (like reports on certain tables or forms that have data blocks of certain tables). I'm doing this by applying the following PL/SQL procedure to a menu item.

```
BEGIN
  RUN_PRODUCT(FORMS/*or REPORTS for reports*/, 'LASTNIKI', SYNCHRONOUS, RUNTIME, FILESYSTEM, '', '');
END;
```

Now, when I start up the main form and navigate my way to the menu item, whenever I click on a menu item that should open up another form I get this message:

*"FRM-92101: There was a failure in the Forms Server during startup. this could happen due to invalid configuration. Please look into the web-server log file for details."*

When I try to click on a menu item that opens up a report, I get the following message:

*"FRM-41842: Run_Product(REPORTS) is no longer supported, use Run_Report_Object instead."*

The reason I'm getting these errors is probably because I'm using a version of Oracle Forms that doesn't support Run_Product() function anymore. What I want to know is how would I run form or report with a command that my version of Oracle Forms supports.

As always, any help would be most welcome. :)

Comment: If you're writing code in a forms Menu, you are already in forms so you don't need to run_product to run forms again - just use `CALL_FORM` or `OPEN_FORM` to open the form. Obviously for reports, the error message is already telling you what to do - use `RUN_REPORT_OBJECT`.

Comment: Can you write an example of both CALL_FORM and RUN_REPORT_OBJECT?

Comment: Not off the top of my head, it's been a while. Open Forms Help, you'll find examples in there.

Comment: Another problem. I tried to use BEGIN RUN_REPORT_OBJECT('trenerclanporocilo'); END; and I got a message 'Wrong number or type of arguments in call to 'RUN_REPORT_OBJECT'. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, as the official documentation clearly states that RUN_REPORT_OBJECT(reportname varchar2) is legal.